# How to solve (Unable to resolve the name 'SIM_OUT.Data'.) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, simulink, simulink-library

I am working on simulink and I am using MATLAB 2022a & 2022b. I used in Simulink To_workspace block
[image]

In order to save data in the workspace of MATLAB.
As shown below

[image]

I got this info when I clicked on out that is available in the workspace.
As shown below

[image]

The data that I want to plot is in SIM_OUT, as shown below:
[image]

When I want to plot the Data column
as below,

```
plot(SIM_OUT.Data)
I get the following error:
Unable to resolve the name 'SIM_OUT.Data'.
```

May I get assistance, please?

Comment: Check if this works:
`plot(out.SIM_OUT);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
plot(out.SIM_OUT)
```